# Session object does not have `request_token`

Tags: api, oauth, dropbox, dropbox-api

So, I'm working with the Dropbox API, and I'm trying to authenticate a user via the Python SDK. I'm able to get the `request_token` from Dropbox. I'm also able to redirect the user to the Dropbox website, to authorize my app.

However, once the user returns to my website (after authorization), I have to recreate the session object with the same `request_token`, in order to get the `access_token`.

I've created a new session object using my `APP_KEY`, `APP_SECRET` and `access_type`. I then try to set the `request_token` for this object using `set_token_request` [SDK method](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-python-sdk-1.4-docs/index.html#dropbox.session.DropboxSession.set_request_token).

After this, I try to get the `access_token` from Dropbox. However, I get an error saying that the session object has no request token.

Here's the code that does that.

```
   sess.set_request_token(oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)
   access_token = sess.obtain_access_token()
```

`sess` is the `DropboxSession` object. `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` returned by Dropbox when I first asked for a `request_token`.

Anybody know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the previous version of the Dropbox SDK for Python.  Downloading the [latest version](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/sdk) should fix the problem.